# Does Crystalline Sliver currently have hexproof or shroud?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Has the text of [Crystalline Sliver](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bCrystalline%20Sliver%5d) been modified to have hexproof, or does it have shroud?  The reason I ask is the [Crypt Sliver](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bCrypt%20Sliver%5d) has

> Tap: Regenerate target sliver

which the Crystalline would make unusable with its old wording.

Answer (score 8):

The current text of a card (called Oracle text) is always available in [Gatherer](http://gatherer.wizards.com/). [Crystalline Sliver](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bCrystalline%20Sliver%5d) now reads:

> All Slivers have shroud. *(They can't be the targets of spells or abilities.)*

Note that Wizards very strongly favors updating cards in ways that *don't* affect the way they work, but simply make them clearer and use more up-to-date terminology or phrasing (called non-functional errata). That's the case here: they just replaced the fully spelled-out ability with the keyword that means the same thing.

Comment: And in case the confusion here stems from Wizards previously changing cards specifically tied to the Hexproof ability (such as [Vines of Vastwood](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=397747)) - even those cards have been changed back to their original meaning, not altering the way they work, as this answer suggests.